# dynamic javascript date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have a script for dynamic javascript date picker, taken from [here](http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker). Please scroll down to **Toggle by Element** which i want to implement but it is not working

```
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
     <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

**edit: i added the following mootools script**

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools-yui-
compressed.js'
type='text/javascript'></script>


      <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></SCRIPT>
      <SCRIPT type="text/css" src="datepicker.css"></SCRIPT>
      <SCRIPT type="text/css" src="datepicker_vista.css"></SCRIPT>
</head>
 <body>    
 <script language="JavaScript">
   window.addEvent('load', function() {
    new DatePicker('.demo_allow_empty', {
    pickerClass: 'datepicker_dashboard',
    allowEmpty: true
 });
  });
 </script>
<label>Datepicker starting at and allowing no value:</label>
<input name='date_allow_empty' type='text' value='' class='date demo_allow_empty' />
</body>
</html>
```

what i am missing?

Comment: it requires mootools , where is your mootools script tag ?

Comment: mootools script tag? i could not get you, i have not added any js or css files except above 4 files, do i need to add something more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it require mootools, i cant see any mootools script tag in your source.
it has nothing to do with jQuery.

edit : here is an exemple :

```
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.2/mootools-yui-compressed.js'
type='text/javascript'></script>
```

put it before the date picker script

Comment: can you please tell me little bit more how to get this mootools script tag?

Comment: i added but same problem is occuring, when i am clicking on that image nothing happens

Comment: it is coming but haphazardly, perhaps i am missing some css files

Comment: it is working in fiddle but not working in my terminal, let me check properly perhaps i am doing wrong somewhere